# If I am not a lawyer, do I have to include a disclaimer about an attorney-client relationship?

Tags: united-states

I'm not, by any means, an admitted lawyer, but I do study law casually in order to better understand the systems of our society.

If someone asks a personal legal question, and a lawyer answers, they have to be fairly explicit about whether they're establishing an attorney-client relationship, at least in the US. However, if *I* answer, and I'm *not* a lawyer, do the same restrictions apply? Am I required to indicate that I am not a lawyer, and I'm not forming an attorney-client relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You cant give legal advice if you arent a lawyer.

If you give someone advice, its a smart thing to tell them that its not real legal advice you are giving them.

If you dont you could end up in a messy situation where someone thinks you gave them legal advice (and thus thinks you are acting as their lawyer) and so the courts think you've committed a crime, since you potentially gave legal advice as a non qualified individual

So to sum up: its not a requirement, but its a smart thing to do.